# Click event takes two clicks to fire in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good afternoon, 
hopefully someone will be able to assist me in diagnosing an issue that I am having on a web form using Post method to submit data to another domain.
within this page I am using asp button control. It is having button_click event.

Now the question is, button click event two clicks. (reason is, one click for button click event. and another is for submitting data to another domain).
I have written form.action method in Button_click event.

Now i want to use one click need to execute button_click event and form should submit to another domain which has given in form.action.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the mediator page having Post method. In the page_Load you need to write this.form.action="desired another domain url". 
Before that take hidden controls and assign values to them.

please refer
http://markchouanard.com/post/35052747409/executing-cross-domain-post-using-jquery-and-asp-net

and for code 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37539/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

To post the data to another domain, in your pages code behind click handler, take the Request.Params and pass it to a WebClient instance's UploadValues function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7.aspx

So now you can have just 1 click that does 2 things in your click event handler, the first thing is process the form submit (doing validation or whatever), then sending it out (HTTP POST using WebClient) to the other domain.